# sendtoaddress not deducting from account

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, sendtoaddress, cli

I have two accounts called "hot" and "cold" and have few address and transactions in each of them. I am trying to move some funds between "hot" to "cold" and using sendtoaddress like this

> bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress "one-of-the-cold-wallet-address" 1.23 "" ""

If i check the balances using

> bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaccount

The balance in "cold" has increased by 1.23 and the balance in "hot" is still the same.

Q1: by default, which account does sendtoaddress uses if i dont have the default account?

Q2: Why did the balance in the "hot" is still the same while the balance in the "cold" increased.

Comment: Did you you try "bitcoin-cli getunconfirmedbalance" for "hot" wallet?